# How to get historical graph of processes activity in Process Exprlorer - Windows Sysinternals

Tags: windows-7, windows, wake-up, process-explorer

I have strange behaviour of laptop during night with no human around. Sometimes fan gets high RPMs and it looks like computer is processing something. It happed also that Laptop waked up by itself few times.
I would like to get 24h history graph of every process that has been running and its resource utilisation. 
Is it possible to get it in ProcessExplorer? 
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: this is not possible with ProcessExplorer. Use [Perfmon](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/BF3082871516A32D86256F2B00447A2E)